# Exercise from Morris's book

Tags: general-topology

I'm beginning to study topology using the Munkres's book, and also the Morris's book Topology without Tears. From the last book, I try to resolve some items of the Exercise 1.1.9, Chapter 1, Pag. 28:

> (iv) $\mathcal{T}_4$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\varnothing$, and every interval $[-r, r]$ for $r$ any positive rational number; is $\mathcal{T}_4$ a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Let $(-s, s)$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, where $s \in \mathbb{Q}, \, s > 0$, and let $[-x, x]$ be all the intervals of $\mathcal{T}_4$ where $x$ is a positive rational number, such that $x<s$. Then $(-s, s)$ is equal to the union of all the intervals $[-x, x]$, but $(-s, s)$ not belong to $\mathcal{T}_4$. Therefore, $\mathcal{T}_4$ is not a topology.

> (v) $\mathcal{T}_5$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$, $\varnothing$, and every interval $(-r, r)$ for $r$ any positive irrational number; is $\mathcal{T}_5$ a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Let $(-s, s)$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, where $s \in \mathbb{Q}, \, s > 0$, and let $(-x, x)$ be all the intervals of $\mathcal{T}_5$ where $x$ is a positive irrational number, such that $x<s$. Then $(-s, s)$ is equal to the union of all the intervals $(-x, x)$, but $(-s, s)$ not belong to $\mathcal{T}_5$. Then, $\mathcal{T}_5$ is not a topology.

I'm quite sure that the first result is correct, but I'm not sure about the second result.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I think you want an irrational $s$ for the counterexample to the first family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

For $s\in\left(0,\infty\right)$ define $A_{s}=\left\{ r\in\left(0,s\right)\mid r\notin\mathbb{Q}\right\} $.

Then $\left(-r,r\right)\in\mathcal{T}$ for each $r\in A_{s}$ and
$\left(-s,s\right)=\bigcup_{r\in A_{s}}\left(-r,r\right)$.

If $\mathcal{T}$ would be a topology then this would imply that $\left(s,-s\right)\in\mathcal{T}$.

However, if $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $\left(s,-s\right)\notin\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: I need to think about it. Thank you very much.